# Salesforce Calander not working on Jquery Popup

Tags: jquery, html, date, calendar, popup

Not able to change date using a datePicker on a Jquery Popup

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please add your code and possibly some screenshots so we can see what actually happens. Also you might want to tidy up your question so it is easier to read and you have more chance on getting a good answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this:

Simply add a class ui-dialog to datePicker and it will work on jquery popup

```
$('.datePicker').addClass('ui-dialog');
```